# Can different contexts create the same object?

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-4.1

I'm working Entity Framework 4.4 into an existing .NET 4.0 application. There is some modularity to it and I need to have one `DbContext` per schema. For example

```
public class AnimalContext : DbContext // animal schema
{
    public IDbSet<Dog> Dogs { get; set; }

    public IDbSet<Cat> Cats { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class FruitContext : DbContext // fruit schema
{
    public IDbSet<Apple> Apples { get; set; }

    public IDbSet<Pear> Pears { get; set; }
}
```

Some entities reference entities in a different schema for example

```
public class Dog
{
    public Apple Apple { get; set; }
}
```

Is there anyway to ensure that the entities created by different contexts are the same? I.E.

```
var animals = new AnimalContext()
var fruits = new FruitContext()

var dog = animals.Dogs.First();
var apple = fruits.Apples.First(x => x == apple)

// and object.ReferenceEquals(apple, dog.Apple)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To ensure that entities created by different `DbContext`s are be the same it is necessary that they share a common `ObjectContext` which can be passed in through the `DbContext` constructor.

The way to create a common `ObjectContext` using the Code First approach is via a `DbModelBuilder` - the recommended way to access one of these is via overriding the [`OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.onmodelcreating%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) method on a class inheriting from `DbContext`.

For example:

```
public class MasterContext : DbContext
{
    public MasterContext(string nameOrConnectionString)
        : base(nameOrConnectionString)
    {
    }

    public static implicit operator ObjectContext(MasterContext obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("obj");
        }

        var adapter = (IObjectContextAdapter)obj;

        return adapter.ObjectContext;
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Dog>();
        modelBuilder.Entity<Cat>();
        modelBuilder.Entity<Apple>();
        modelBuilder.Entity<Pear>();
    }
}

public class AnimalContext : DbContext
{
    public AnimalContext(ObjectContext context)
        : base(context, false)
    {
    }

    public IDbSet<Dog> Dogs { get; set; }

    public IDbSet<Cat> Cats { get; set; }
}

public class FruitContext : DbContext
{
    public FruitContext(ObjectContext context)
        : base(context, false)
    {
    }

    public IDbSet<Apple> Apples { get; set; }

    public IDbSet<Pear> Pears { get; set; }
}

//...
var master = new MasterContext("my connection")
var animals = new AnimalContext(master)
var fruits = new FruitContext(master)

var dog = animals.Dogs.First();
var apple = fruits.Apples.First(x => x == apple)

// Passes
Debug.Assert(object.ReferenceEquals(apple, dog.Apple))
```

The important thing to note here is that `OnModelCreating` in the `MasterContext` must register every type used in all of the slave `DbContexts` (you can obviously slicken this up  to automatically register everything you need to).

Comment: If you use this approach it doesn't make sense to use slave contexts at all. You can simply use the master context.

Comment: The question is not whether or not it makes sense to you, the question is how you do it. You said that you can't do it, but you can. Using this approach the master context can be generated at runtime and the modular slave contexts can live in their respective assemblies. There is quite a lot of resistance in my team to not writing  lengthy boilerplate SPs and cumbersome DA components that call them and I think that presenting at least the illusion of a modular approach to adopting EF will make it easier to persuade people that this is the right way to do things.

Comment: I just wanted to point out that this is not what your original question asked for - these entities are not created by different contexts, they are created and all managed by single master context.

Comment: No they are clearly created by different `DbContexts` however those `DbContexts` share a common `ObjectContext` that is exactly what I asked. I'm afraid you are wrong on this one.

Comment: `DbContext`s are just wrappers around `ObjectContext` - they don't contain any logic related to "creating entity". If you share the `ObjectContext` your entities are indeed created by single shared master context. If you are doing this just to have clear design it will work but if you are using multiple contexts to avoid performance and other problems related to big models you have just brought that problem back into your code.

Comment: Did I ever say anything about performance? All I wanted was to make the design more modular. That I clearly stated. You need to stop second guessing.

Answer (score 0):

Entities created by different contexts (even different instances of the same context type) will not be same.

IMHO you must handle it yourselves by not allowing `AnimalContext` to create instances of objects defined in `FruitContext` - in your case `Apple` entity and assigning `Apple` to `Dog` after it is loaded by `FruitContext` - you will need to expose `AppleId` property on `Dog`. This could be probably somehow automated by handling the inter connection in `ObjectContext.ObjectMaterialized` event handler but it can slow down your object loading and it can make your contexts tightly coupled.

You can use either `NotMapped` attribute on `Apple` property or dog or use `Ignore` in fluent mapping for `Apple` class or `Apple` property in `AnimalContext`'s mapping definition. If `Apple` has inverse navigation property to `Dog`, you will also have to ignore `Dog` on `FruitContext`.

Comment: You can do this, see my answer below.